# Outbound Message vs WS callout

Tags: webservices, workflowoutboundmessage

I have got an requirement where I need to update the Oracle system. I am confused on what should I do .

Should I make Outbound message ?
Should I consume their WSDL and update the records with Service call.

Please tell me when to use Outbound and when to use WS callout

Thanks.

Comment: have you read this? 'Choosing the right integration strategy' : http://events.developerforce.com/conferences/dreamforce?session=7601

Answer (score 3):

At a very high level both will work in many scenarios, but more complex scenarios cannot be accomplished with Outbound Messaging.  I think the rule of thumb is similar to clicks vs. code.  Outbound messaging can be leveraged with workflows and configuration within the UI of Salesforce.  Making callouts to Web Services requires writing apex.

We generally preach top use configuration and native SF such as Workflow Rules, Assignment Rules, Validation Rules, Approval Processes etc. when you can.  Use Apex, Visualforce, etc. sparingly and as you need to.

I think the same can apply here, if your specific requirement can be accomplished with outbound messaging, you should likely choose that route as its a standard functionality of the platform and much of the leg work is done for you.  Web service callouts are custom code that you will have to maintain moving forward.

This is also mentioned int eh documentation for SOAP services found here (https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm)[1](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm)

> Use Outbound Messaging to handle integration solutions when possible.
>   Use callouts to third-party Web services only when necessary.

Again, I can't speak to your exact, specific scenario, but I think this is a decent 'general' rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

Outbound Messages have very precise [XML markup](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_wsdl.htm) that they will send out based on a Workflow Rule being triggered. If you cannot customize the target systems endpoint to consume that WSDL, the Outbound Message will be of minimal use to you.

A web service callout is much more flexible as you can customize the outbound message markup, but obviously requires some code to be written.

Answer (score 0):

Outbound messages are sent from workflow and if the the service that is called has to be built to match the Salesforce generated WSDL specification, not an existing WSDL.

So in your scenario, since there already is a service built that you need to call you should consume their WSDL and make the web service call